# Views exposed filter using Solr only returning results for exact phrase

Tags: search, views

We're using a Views exposed filter (using the Search API Solr) that searches a Solr index to search for node titles, but only seeing exact phrases matched.

For example, if we have a node titled 'Trees of the Eastern Seaboard,' and do a search for 'Trees,' the node is returned. If we search for 'Trees of' the node is also returned. However if we search for 'Trees Seaboard,' no results are returned.

The Solr search index is using the 'Fulltext' setting. I've tried switching it to 'String' but that setting returns no results at all for the view.

The default search is also configured to use Solr, and returns results correctly for 'Trees Seaboard.'

Is there a way to allow the Views exposed filter to return the correct results for not exact phrases? (keywords?)

Is there a way to allow the filter to accept a 'contains any' setting for the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a screenshot of the basic search view that we setup for our Search API + Apache SOLR configuration:

[image: Search View Screenshot]

The settings for the filter can be shown here:

[image: Filter Settings]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks David. We did not have the filter configured correctly - it was looking at only the indexed node, which did not have the operator option to select 'Contains any of these words' - I switched it out to match your example & it's working properly.